# Android: Where to store an Object

Tags: android, object, singleton, p2p

I'm using a library named Sip2Peer to implement a basic P2P system. Each device is a Peer and needs to have an instance of the class SimplePeer stored somewhere. This object is used to send messages.

I need to access this object from an activity and from two BroadcastReceivers. I wanted to store it in the application class, but since the application instance retrieved in the BroadcastReceivers (getApplicationContext) isn't the same as the application instance retrieved in the activity I couldn't use it.

Then I decided to create a class named PeerManager that stores this SimplePeer as a static object, but when I try to access it from the BroadcastReceivers the SimplePeer is null.

PeerManager class:

```
public class PeerManager {

private static SimplePeer peer = null;


public static SimplePeer getPeer() {
    return PeerManager.peer;
}

public static void setPeer(SimplePeer peer) {
    PeerManager.peer = peer;
}

public static void createPeer(Context context, String username) {
    try{            
        PeerManager.peer = new SimplePeer(...);
        ...
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

This is how I access it in my Activity and BroadcastReceivers:

```
if(PeerManager.getPeer()==null){
            Log.d("AA", "New Peer");
            PeerManager.createPeer(mContext, username);
        }
        else{
            PeerManager.getPeer().logInfo();
            PeerManager.getPeer().joinToPeer(PeerManager.getPeer().getBootstrapPeerAddress());
        }
```

I executed this code twice in my Activity and the first time the "New Peer" message is shown, the next one isn't. But after that, when my BroadcastReceiver is executed, the "New Peer" message is shown again, and it shouldn't. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong?

----------------- EDIT ------------------------------

I tried to apply the Singleton pattern to my SimplePeer class. This is the class:

```
public class SimplePeer extends Peer {

    private Context mContext;

    private static SimplePeer instance = null;

    public SimplePeer(String pathConfig, String key, Context context) {
        super(pathConfig, key);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public static SimplePeer getInstance(String pathConfig, String key, Context context){
         if(instance==null){
            Log.d("SIMPLE PEER", "New instance");
            instance = new SimplePeer(pathConfig, key, context);
            instance.contactSBC();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
```

}

The result is the same as before: when I use SimplePeer.getInstance(...) in my Activity the instance is created the first time, but the second time isn't. If then I use SimplePeer.getInstance(...) in my BroadcastReceiver the instance is created again.

Answer (score 1):

that's a classic Singleton pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

```
    public class PeerManager{

       // Instance
       private static PeerManager me;

       // Private constructor
       private PeerManager(){}

       // Access
       public PeerManager get(){
          if(me==null) me = new PeerManager();
          return me;
       }

       // the rest of your implementation
    }
```

I hope it makes sense.
That way you guarantee that you always only have one object and is always instantiated.

Comment: FYI, Singleton = only one instance of an object.

Comment: The object I'm trying to save is SimplePeer, PeerManager is just an extra class I created to store the SimplePeer instance. Is still that implementation? I tried to apply the singleton pattern I saw in your link to my SimplePeer class but it's not working either. I edited the main post to show you what I did.